# angular2: how to test a component which has an observable time interval

Tags: unit-testing, angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, observable

I have a slide-show component that has an Input array of slide objects and shows each one as long as it's been defined in `slide.time` of itself. also there are two buttons that clicking them has to slide to the next item and reset the timer. in order to make this work, I'm using Observables like this:

```js
/**
 * a "SUBJECT" for pausing(restarting) the slider's auto-slide on user's click on left and right arrows
 * @type {Subject}
 */
private pauser = new Subject();

/**
 * the main observable for timer (before adding the pause/reset option)
 * @type {Observable<T>}
 */
private source = Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .map(function (x) { /*return x.value + ':' + x.interval;*/ return x })
    .share();

/**
 * the final timer, which can be paused
 * @type {Observable<R>}
 */
private pausableSource = this.pauser.switchMap(paused => paused ? Observable.never() : this.source);

/**
 * the subscription to the timer which is assigned at OnInit hook , and destroyed at OnDestroy
 */
private subscription;

ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.pausableSource.subscribe(() => {
        //doing changes to the template and changing between slides
    });
    this.pauser.next(false);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

and it's working properly. 
now to test this component, I'm giving it some data within a test-host component and want to check it's functionality like this:

```js
it("should show the second (.slidingImg img) element after testHost.data[0].time seconds 
    have passed (which here, is 2 seconds)", () => {
    //testing
});
```

i tried many things that i found in docs or anywhere on the internet, but none of them work for me. the problem is that I can't mock the passage of time in a way that the observable timer would perform next actions, and it's like no time has passed whatsoever. two of the ways that haven't worked for me are these:

```js
it("should show the second (.slidingImg img) element after testHost.data[0].time seconds 
    have passed (which here, is 2 seconds)", fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(2500);
    flushMicrotasks();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let secondSlidingImg = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.slidingImg'))[1].query(By.css('img'));
    expect(secondSlidingImg).toBeTruthy();
    //error: expected null to be truthy
}));
```

i got this from angular2 docs.

and:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);

    testHost = fixture.componentInstance;

    scheduler = new TestScheduler((a, b) => expect(a).toEqual(b));

    const originalTimer = Observable.interval;
    spyOn(Observable, 'interval').and.callFake(function(initialDelay, dueTime) {
        return originalTimer.call(this, initialDelay, dueTime, scheduler);
    });
    // or:
    // const originalTimer = Observable.timer;
    // spyOn(Observable, 'timer').and.callFake(function(initialDelay, dueTime) {
    //     return originalTimer.call(this, initialDelay, dueTime, scheduler);
    // });
    scheduler.maxFrames = 5000;

});
it("should show the second (.slidingImg img) element after testHost.data[0].time seconds 
    have passed (which here, is 2 seconds)", async(() => {
    scheduler.schedule(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let secondSlidingImg = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.slidingImg'))[1].query(By.css('img'));
        expect(secondSlidingImg).toBeTruthy();
        //error: expected null to be truthy
    }, 2500, null);
    scheduler.flush();
}));
```

i got this approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167415/unit-test-rxjs-observable-timer-using-typescript-karma-and-jasmine).

so I desperately need to know how exactly should I simulate time passage in my unit test so that the component's observable time interval would really trigger...

versions:

```
angular: "2.4.5"
"rxjs": "5.0.1"
"jasmine": "~2.4.1"
"karma": "^1.3.0"
"typescript": "~2.0.10"
"webpack": "2.2.1"
```

Comment: Victor Savkin wrote an [excellent blog post](https://blog.nrwl.io/controlling-time-with-zone-js-and-fakeasync-f0002dfbf48c) about that, you should read it :)

Comment: did you mean a special part of the post? because I just read it a couple of times and I think it's only relative solution for me is the use of `fakeAsync` and `tick(/*some second*/)` which is the first solution that i mentioned and is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

`fakeAsync` doesn't work for some case with RxJs. You need to manually move internal timer in RxJs. Something along those lines:

```
import {async} from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';
...

describe('faking internal RxJs scheduler', () => {
  let currentTime: number;

  beforeEach(() => {
    currentTime = 0;
    spyOn(async, 'now').and.callFake(() => currentTime);
  });

  it('testing RxJs delayed execution after 1000ms', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Do your stuff
    fixture.detectChanges();
    currentTime = 1000;
    tick(1000);
    discardPeriodicTasks();

    expect(...);
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found for testing this is Marble Testing:

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

You can control emits by order and time, which seems to be exactly what you need.